# convert java project into windows service

Tags: java, windows, service

I am creating an application, where it will be used by other users. 
I need to run that in system of users so that it runs as a windows service. How this can be achieved? In this case user will download the application(probably as .exe or any other format) and it will start automatically as a windows service.

Thanks in advance for any response,

Comment: ...or like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815956/javaexe-and-java-application-as-windows-system-service-interactive-to-desktop