# Java Service Wrapper and JNA

Tags: java, service, jna, java-service-wrapper

I built a small application to retrieve the name of the windows frames that are running on the desktop, using the JNA library.

I also use the library from the [java service wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/howto-system-library-path.html), but when I start my application with the wrapper I cannot receive all the need information.
It is not recognizing anything that is running on the dekstop.

If I start the application without the wrapper everything is ok. I think the wrapper is "blocking" the request of the JNA library.

Can someone give me a hint where to check?

Comment: your problem is called "restriction interactive services" or "session 0 isolation". look toward : [Java Service Wrapper to start program with Interactive Desktop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846419/java-service-wrapper-to-start-program-with-interactive-desktop/17887651#17887651) [Java application as windows system service interactive to desktop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815956/javaexe-and-java-application-as-windows-system-service-interactive-to-desktop/16822685#16822685)

Comment: Thank I wiil look foward

Comment: Hi I tested with the solution offered but is not what i need, I read from microsoft what is happening and I understand, for the moment this a limit imputed by them, I have to search for another solution.